# CSV to Excel using Pandas misplaces header

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am converting a csv to excel using Pandas library using this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('imported_license.csv')
print(df.head())
df.to_excel('imported_license.xlsx')
```

But when it reads the csv it misplaces the header i.e. header moves two cells forward. What should I do to avoid this?
Here is the csv snippet:

[image]

The issue arrives on reading csv:
[image]

And this is what it looks like in excel:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `df.to_excel('imported_license.xlsx', merge_cells=False)`?

Comment: It didn't work because the issue arrives when it reads the csv.

Comment: Does it read the csv as a multi-index, or are the column names already wrong when you read in the csv? How do the first lines of text from the csv look (so as text, not in Excel)?

Comment: I just made the edit. Column names are misplaced when it reads the csv.

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.read_csv('imported_license.csv', index_col=False)`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you post this as answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it doesn't read in the csv properly. Try using `index_col=False`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('imported_license.csv', index_col=False)
df.to_excel('imported_license.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to..

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Reading the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('imported_license.csv') 

# saving xlsx file 
license_xlsx = pd.ExcelWriter('imported_license.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(license_xlsx, index=False) 

license_xlsx.save()
```